# Mockito.any() pass Interface with Generics

Tags: java, generics, mockito

is it possible to pass the type of an interface with generics?

The interface:

```
public interface AsyncCallback<T>
```

In my test method:

```
Mockito.any(AsyncCallback.class)
```

Putting `<ResponseX>` behind or for `.class` didnt work.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

There is a type-safe way: use `ArgumentMatchers.any()` and qualify it with the type:

```
ArgumentMatchers.<AsyncCallback<ResponseX>>any()
```

Comment: I confirm this answer works and correctly suppresses the warning.

Comment: This isn't really safer since the actual method can only be called with the correctly typed argument anyway.  It was just necessary to satisfy the pre-java8 compiler which lacked this kind of type inference.

Comment: I used something like this 
 ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>> responseEntity = Matchers.<ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>>> any();

And it always returns null

Comment: With new versions of Mockito: `(Matchers.<AsyncCallback<ResponseX>>any()`

Comment: `Matchers` is actually deprecated, but `ArgumentMatchers` did work.

Comment: The first one using ArgumentMatchers worked for me and the second one using Matchers is deprecated.  I had some confusion on what is ResponseX. however got the answer myself, in my case i wrote like this : ArgumentMatchers.<Specification<Call>>any()

Comment: How to write it in Kotlin?

Comment: `ArgumentMatchers.<List<S8Z2DETNSGDto>>any()` - IDE hints me that Explicit type arguments can be inferred. It means that there is no requirement to explicitly define types and `ArgumentMatchers.any()` will have the same result

Comment: This also works using just `Mockito.<AsyncCallback<ResponseX>>any()`.

Comment: But hold on!  `any()` and `any(Class<T>)` do not do the same thing.  The no-arg matches anything, but the 1-arg only matches things of that class.  So how can do you this where, like the original poster, you need to use `any(Class)` and not `any()`?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic -- yup, same question here. Not possible with silly Java generics?

Answer (score 82):

Using Java 8, you can simply use `any()` (assuming static import) without argument or type parameter because of enhanced type inference.  The compiler now knows from the target type (the type of the method argument) that you actually mean `Matchers.<AsyncCallback<ResponseX>>any()`, which is the pre-Java 8 solution.

Comment: Wouldn't `any()` match `AsyncCallback<AnyOtherType>` as well?

Comment: @MatthewRead  Using `AsyncCallback<AnyOtherType>` should not even compile if the argument type is 'AsyncCallback<ResponseX>'.

Comment: I'm wondering about a situation where the argument type is generic as well, but you only want to mock it for one concrete type (or mock it for multiple types in different ways). Given `when(x.y(any())).thenAnswer(...)` for example, where `y` is `public <T> T y(AsyncCallback<T> arg)`.  Perhaps it would be better to check the type in the answer, if that is what's needed?

Comment: @MatthewRead Due to erasure, the actual type cannot be checked at runtime by Mockito.  So you can't even use `isA()`.  If the object holds a `Class` object corresponding to the type, and the interface exposes this, I guess you could check it in a custom matcher.  Or for example in case of a `Collection` you could check the type of the elements.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right.  I was actually just reading more on type erasure and for some reason didn't connect it to this.  Thanks for explaining!

Comment: `Matchers` was replaced by `ArgumentMatchers` in Mockito v2

Comment: This is only true when there is not a conflicting method overload, and you need to tell the compiler which one to call. e.g. `myMethod(Type1)` & `myMethod(Type2)` you can't just do `myMethod(any())`.

Comment: Is it some JAVA8 feature allowing to avoid type checks? Could you please let me know where I can read about it?

Comment: @YuraHoy No runtime type check is being done here even before version 8.  The type had to be added just to satisfy the compiler.  Now the compiler infers the type from the method signature.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Answer (score 23):

I had to adopt the following mechamism to allow for generics:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
List<String> list = any();
when(callMyMethod.getResult(list)).thenReturn(myResultString);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: See my answer: this is no longer necessary with Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

Posting pierrefevrier comment as answer which might be useful if it present in a answer instead of comments.

With new versions of Mockito: `(Matchers.<AsyncCallback<ResponseX>>any()`

Comment: i added his comment to the original answer

Answer (score 4):

Further to thSoft's answer putting the qualified call to any() in method meant I could remove the qualification since the return type allowed inference:

```
private HashMap<String, String> anyStringStringHashMap() {
    return Matchers.any();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem using Spring `Example`:

```
Mockito.when(repo.findAll(Mockito.<Example<SrvReqToSupplierComment>>any()))
            .thenReturn(Lists.emptyList());
```

Here, you have to use qualification, b/c findAll method can take multiple types, like `Sort` and `Iterable`.  You can also use `Mockito.any(Example.class)` of course with the type safety warning.

Comment: It was my problem too. I use generally a static import for org.mockito.Mockito.*, but in this case only the when() method could be used without qualification, the any() method needs the qualification.

Answer (score 1):

Using a qualified generics type with the no-argument `any()` method works (i.e. `ArgumentMatchers.<AsyncCallback<ResponseX>>any()`), but can get unwieldy for longer generics expressions.  An alternative is to put a no-argument `any()` call in its own generic method, using the specific generic type as the return type:

```java
private static <T> AsyncCallback<T> anyAsyncCallback() {
  return ArgumentMatchers.any()
}
```

### Usage

```java
Mockito.verify(mockObject).performCallback(any(), anyAsyncCallback())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it, adding suppress warnings if you like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
AsyncCallback<ResponseX> callback = Mockito.any(AsyncCallback.class)
```

If Java allowed 'generic' generics they could have a method like this which is what you are looking for

```
private static <T, E> T<E> mock(Class<T<E>> clazz)
```

Comment: When I tried this, I received an error in my test: `You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.`

Comment: Not a good idea to use `@SuppressWarnings`: pre-java 8, if you were going to assign it to a separate variable, you could just use `any()` as in theINtoy's answer.  Now with java 8, `any()` can be used inline without the need for a separate assignment.

Comment: @kevinarpe if you have multiple argument matchers they must be called in order as the Java language specifies.