# Mockito isA(Class<T> clazz) How to resolve type safety?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-5

in my test I have the following line:

```
when(client.runTask(anyString(), anyString(), isA(Iterable.class)).thenReturn(...)
```

`isA(Iterable.class)` produces warning that it needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Iterable<Integer>` . What is syntax for that?

```
isA(Iterable<Integer>.class)
isA((Iterable<Integer>)Iterable.class
```

do not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mockito.any() pass Interface with Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917635/mockito-any-pass-interface-with-generics)

Answer (score 31):

### Mockito/Hamcrest and generic classes

Yes, this is a general problem with Mockito/Hamcrest. Generally using `isA()` with generic classes produces a warning.

There are predifined Mockito matchers for the most common generic classes: [anyList()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyList()), `anyMap()`, `anySet()` and `anyCollection()`.

Suggestions:

### anyIterable() in Mockito 2.1.0

Mockito 2.1.0 added a new [anyIterable()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyIterable()) method for matching Iterables:

```
when(client.runTask(anyString(), anyString(), anyIterable()).thenReturn(...)
```

### Ignore in Eclipse

If you just want to get rid of the warning in Eclipse. Option exists since [Eclipse Indigo](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/eclipse-news-part2.html#unavoidable-generic-type-problems):

> Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Generic
>   types > Ignore unavoidable generic type problems

### Quick Fix with @SuppressWarnings

I suggest you do this if you have the problem only once. I personally don't remember ever needing an `isA(Iterable.class)`.

As Daniel Pryden says, you can limit the `@SuppressWarnings` to a local variable or a helper method.

### Use a generic isA() matcher with TypeToken

This solves the problem for good. But it has two disadvantages:

- The syntax is not too pretty and might confuse some people.
- You have an additional dependency on the library providing the `TypeToken` class. Here I used the [TypeToken class from Guava](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html). There's also a `TypeToken` class in Gson and a `GenericType` in JAX-RS.

Using the generic matcher:

```
import static com.arendvr.matchers.InstanceOfGeneric.isA;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat;

// ...

when(client.runTask(anyString(), anyString(), argThat(isA(new TypeToken<Iterable<Integer>>() {}))))
            .thenReturn(...);
```

Generic matcher class:

```
package com.arendvr.matchers;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

public class InstanceOfGeneric<T> implements ArgumentMatcher<T> {
    private final TypeToken<T> typeToken;

    private InstanceOfGeneric(TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        this.typeToken = typeToken;
    }

    public static <T> InstanceOfGeneric<T> isA(TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        return new InstanceOfGeneric<>(typeToken);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        return item != null && typeToken.getRawType().isAssignableFrom(item.getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: An arguably better API (compared to a bunch of "anyList", "anyIterable", ... methods) would be to have a `T any(T)` method. In JMockit, for example, one can write the following while avoiding an "unchecked" warning: `Iterable<Integer> col = null; client.runTask(anyString, anyString, withAny(col));`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I do:

```
// Cast from Class<Iterable> to Class<Iterable<Integer>> via the raw type.
// This is provably safe due to erasure, but will generate an unchecked warning
// nonetheless, which we suppress.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<Iterable<Integer>> klass 
    = (Class<Iterable<Integer>>) (Class) Iterable.class;  

// later

isA(klass) // <- now this is typesafe
```

Comment: Worked for me like this but with `@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the statement.  No other way but if it bothers you, you can move the cast to a helper method.

Comment: This is to say: suck it up, there's no way to do this that doesn't involve an unchecked cast.

Comment: Yes, although you could hide it in a helper method if it makes you feel better :P

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. To simplify, you can't initialize this variable without warning :

```
Class<Iterable<Integer>> iterableIntegerClass = ?
```

One solution might be to use the [pseudo-typedef antipattern](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02216/index.html),
,you create and use an `IntegerIterable` interface

```
interface IntegerIterable extends Iterable<Integer> {}
```

then

```
isA(IntegerIterable.class)
```

will no more produce warning. But you will have to extend the class implementing `Iterable` to let them implements `IntegerIterable` :) For example :

```
public class IntegerArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer> implements IntegerIterable {}
```

Mmm tasty...

So, i will sugest you to consider to just paper over the cracks by adding to your method :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```