# How to resolve "The expression of type Class needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class<Object>"

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, data-access

I have the ff. test method:

```
@Mock
private DBAccessor accessor;

/**
 * Successful find().
 */
@Test
public void testFind() {
    // Prepare
    MockDto mockDto = mock(MockDto.class);
    try {
        when(accessor.executeQuery(any(Class.class), anyString(), any(ConcurrentHashMap.class))).thenReturn(
                mockDto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Unexpected exception.");
    }
}
```

However, the ff. warning occcurs:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type safety: Unchecked invocation executeQuery(Class, String, ConcurrentHashMap) of the generic method executeQuery(Class<T>, String, Object) of type DBAccessor
    - Type safety: The expression of type Class needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class<Object>
```

How do I resolve the above warnings?

I'm using Mockit and Powermock as mocking frameworks and JUnit.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: Thanks. Just found the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012249/mockito-isaclasst-clazz-how-to-resolve-type-safety

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the ff. [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012249/mockito-isaclasst-clazz-how-to-resolve-type-safety), it can be removed by `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.