# How to mock any list of any generic type in Mockito Java

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Mockito and run into an issue with mocking list of generic types.
Here is an example:

```
class Foo<T>{}
..
int IKnowHotToMockThisMethod(List<String> listString){}
int IWantToMockThisMethod(List<Foo> listFoo){}
```

So for first method I can do

```
Mockito.when(myMock.IKnowHotToMockThisMethod(any(List.class)).thenReturn(1);
```

Which works just fine, but how can I mock second method for given type (String)?
When I did:

```
Mockito.when(myMock.IWantToMockThisMethod(anyListOf(Foo.class)).thenReturn(1);
```

I've got warnings that `Foo<String>` was expected
How to set mock to accept  `anyListOf Foo<String>` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917635/mockito-any-pass-interface-with-generics