# Mockito and RestTemplate with generic types

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to unit test the following Spring boot code with RestTemplate sending a request to the API and retrieving some resources from it:

```
final URI targetUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUri)
                .path("/myEntities").build().toUri();

final RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.get(targetUri).accept(HAL_JSON).build();
final Resources<MyEntity> resourceAccounts = restTemplate.exchange(request, new ResourcesType<MyEntity>() {
        }).getBody();
```

In the unit test, I am mocking this request-response using Mockito:

```
final Resources<MyEntity> myEntities = new Resources<>(myEntityList, links);
final ResponseEntity<Object> response = new ResponseEntity<Object>(myEntities, HttpStatus.OK);

when(restTemplate.exchange(any(RequestEntity.class), any(ResourcesType.class))).thenReturn(response);
```

It works fine but I am getting `Unchecked invocation exchanged` because I am not using the generics correctly.

I just wonder what is the correct and bullet-proof way of doing this? I tried casting the `ResponseEntity` type to `MyEntity` but this does causes compile exception (the constructor `ResponseEntity<MyEntity> is undefined`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With type safe method of `Matchers` ? One of the way to check method invocations with the generics.

`Matchers.<ResponseType<MyEntity>>.any()`

[Source](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any()) - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917635/mockito-any-pass-interface-with-generics)

To check the response of a method, `ArgumentCaptor` can be used.