# The method play(Class<T>) is not applicable for the arguments (Class)

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I have this code:

```
when(mockedObject.play(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(object);
```

The header of the method `play` is like this:

```
public Object play(Class<T> classz)
```

When I run my test I get this error:

> The method `play(Class<T>)` is not applicable for the arguments `(Class)`

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917635) is similar.  You want:

```
when(mockedObject.play(Matchers.<Class<T>>any())).thenReturn(object);
```

Or in Java 8 you can just call:

```
when(mockedObject.play(Matchers.any())).thenReturn(object);
```

Assuming that `T` is a generic of the object you've mocked, you'll want to replace it with whatever you've instantiated `mockedObject` with.  So, if you've got something like this:

```
@Mock
Foo<Bar> mockedObject;
```

You'll want to use:

```
when(mockedObject.play(Matchers.<Class<Bar>>any())).thenReturn(object);
```

Comment: I found in the same discussion that using Java 8, I can simply use `any()`. it works :) Thanks!

Comment: yes, correct.  In Java 8, the Generalized Target-type Inference improvement can work out what generic is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting, by doing this:

```
when(mockedObject.play((Class<?>)any(Class.class))).thenReturn(object);
```