# mock generics in java

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a get method that takes 3 inputs and that needs to be mocked-

1. Request - okhttp3.Request
2. JSONUnmarshaler - Generic java object
3. GSON - com.google.gson.Gson

   **when(this.okhttpclient.get(any(Request.class), any(JSONUnmarshaler.class), any(Gson.class)).thenReturn(response);**

I was able to mock the Request and GSON object but not sure how to mock the JSONUnmarshaler object. It is a Java generics object and here is the interface definition for it.

```
public interface JSONUnmarshaler<T> {
       T fromJSON(Gson gson, JsonElement json);
    }
```

Response type:-

```
List<Course> course_list = new ArrayList<Course>();
course_list.add(new Course());
UdemyResponse<List<Course>> response = new UdemyResponse<List<Course>>(200,"teststring","raw_data",course_list);
```

Comment: what have you tried? what's the error?

Comment: I tried the above code but it throws me a warning so not sure if its correct -  Type safety: The expression of type JSONUnmarshaler needs unchecked conversion to conform to JSONUnmarshaler<Object>

Comment: Use Matchers.<JSONUnmarshaler<T>>any(). from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932751/3289669

Comment: @Azizi: thanks, that worked for when clause, my return type is also generics, how can I handle that?